# Help with longtable renders extra field

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple, filecontents

So I have a problem because my longtable seems always render one extra field in my table.
Depending on where I put my \ it renders after it goes through the csv or before.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         %Set to icelandic for icelandic documents
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}          % For coloring tables rows
\usepackage{csvsimple}              % Used to import from csv files to tables

\usepackage{longtable}              % For tables spanning multiple pages

\usepackage{filecontents}


\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.3cm}} % ATA CHAPTER
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}} % Registration code
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}} % Faults/corredctive
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents*}{csv/pireps.dat}
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
        a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
    \end{filecontents*}
    \begin{center}
        \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
        \begin{longtable}{|R|T|T|A|F|F|A|A|}

            \caption{Summary of PIREPS for}
            \label{grid_mlmmh} \\\hline 
            \rowcolor{gray!50}
            \multicolumn{1}{|R|}{\textbf{Reg. code}} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{T|}{\textbf{Found on date}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{T|}{\textbf{Closed on date}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{ATA Chapter}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{F|}{\textbf{Fault description}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{F|}{\textbf{Corrective action}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{Flight number}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{Fault source}}\\\hline
            \endfirsthead

            \rowcolor{white!50}
            \multicolumn{8}{c}%

            {{\bfseries PIREPS -- continued from previous page}} \\\hline 
            \rowcolor{gray!50}
            \multicolumn{1}{|R|}{\textbf{Reg. code}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{T|}{\textbf{Found on date}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{T|}{\textbf{Closed on date}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{ATA chapter}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{F|}{\textbf{Fault description}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{F|}{\textbf{Corrective action}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{Flight number}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{A|}{\textbf{Fault source}}
            \endhead

            \hline \multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
            \endfoot

            \endlastfoot

            \csvreader[separator=semicolon, head to column names]{csv/pireps.dat}{}
            {\a & \b & \c & \d & \e & \f & \g & \h\\}
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a linebreak after every CSV row, and listings also calls a linebreak before inserting the foot, such that you have a row with just one empty cell after your CSV input.

Resolve this by using `late after line` option of `\csvreader`: You can use this to specify a linebreak after every CSV row except for the last one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{csv-pireps.dat}
    a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
    a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
    a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
    a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
    a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Summary of PIREPS for}
    \\\hline
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\\hline
    \endfirsthead

    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \csvreader[separator=semicolon, head to column names, late after line=\\]{csv-pireps.dat}{}
        {\a & \b & \c & \d & \e & \f & \g & \h}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]